# AWS Lambda Serverless Framework Custom Fonts - Vuetify .woff .ttf files are not rendering

Tags: lambda, vuetify.js, serverless, truetype, woff

I've used the serverless framework to deploy my Vuetify build to an AWS lambda function / API gateway. Everything is rendering properly locally with `npx serve -s dist`
However, when I use express to serve the application over lambda/api gateway, all the files are fetched properly through the network, but the vuetify icons are not rendered.
I receive the errors:

`OTS parsing error: Size of decompressed WOFF 2.0 is less than compressed size`

`Failed to decode downloaded font`

These files are not corrupted, I can download them over the network, replace my local files, and everything works as expected.
Also, I can host the application via S3 and the S3 server correctly renders the icons from the WOFF files with 'Content-Type': 'binary/octet-stream'
I'd like to be able to host the application on an AWS lambda so I can include authorization / redirect logic, using S3 with a lambda authorizer is not a feasible option at this point.

Please advise on why the express implementation of my lambda function cannot render Vuetify icons via these 'materialdesignicons.woff' files

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about [serverless-http](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-http) library, one can set binary media types explicitly. Here is how:

```
serverless(app, {
    binary: ['font/*']
});
```

It should fix the issue. More examples in the [documentation](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-http/blob/master/docs/ADVANCED.md#binary-mode).